# I have a problems with adding tooltips in javascript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have 3 fields and every field have different tooltip. How can I get right tooltip to right field? :) Without making 3 others scripts to each other field.
My code looking like that:

this is my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".mybox").hover(function(){

        $(".tooltip").css("display", "block");},
        function(){
        $(".tooltip").css("display", "none");

        });

        $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        var mx = event.pageX+15;
        var my = event.pageY+15;
        $(".tooltip").css("left", mx+"px").css("top", my+"px");

        });

    });
```

this is my css:

```
.mybox {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    magrgin-top: 100px;
    width:250px;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center
    }
.tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: orange;

    border-radius: 5px;
    display:none;
    }
```

and my html look like that code:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div class="mybox">
      aaa
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      ddd
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="mybox">
      bbb
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      eee
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="mybox">
      ccc
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
      fff
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Some ideas? :)

Comment: `[id]` attributes are required to be unique. Use `[class]` instead.

Comment: ok. when I use class they show me all toolboxes to one box...

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `mousemove` event? you are placing all of them together that way in the same time all of them will be displayed together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements on the page with the same ID.

Perhaps something like this would work: Note, you have to change your CSS associations to classes rather than IDs

```
HTML:
<div>
    <div class="mybox">
    bbb
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip">
    ccc
    </div>
</div>


JS:
            $(".mybox").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).next('.tooltip').show();
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).next('.tooltip').hide();
            });
```